# jQuery mobile: Meaningful URL for a dialog page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to link to a dialog, and have it display as a dialog?

In other words:

1. Open a dialog from an underlying page
2. Bookmark the URL
3. Open a new browser tab
4. Paste the URL
5. Have the dialog open up in front of its underlying page

I can't see how to link to [the dialogs in the jQuery Mobile demo](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html&ui-state=dialog) (or [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/multipage-template.html#foo&ui-state=dialog)) - if I copy the URLs, and reopen them, the underlying page opens but not the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is specify on your link that it should open the target as a dialog.

In the example on that documentation page you posted, the dialog-opening link is written as:

```
<a href="foo.html" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
```

If you are having problems, I'd suggest ensuring that your pages are setup properly (whether you are fetching them by Ajax or not).

**EDIT**

Let's say your base page is: `www.example.com`. The dialog page content is stored at `www.example.com/dialog.html`. If you wanted to send a dialoged link to someone, I would do it like this:

Add a hashtag to the end of the base url: `www.example.com/#dialog=dialog%3Fhtml`. The page would then look to see if it has any `#dialog=` at the end of its URL. If it does, programatically open the dialog. If you'd like some example code, feel free to ask.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased the question badly. I meant is it possible to give a dialog page a meaningful URL, and bookmark that URL. On re-opening the URL, have the page display again as a dialog.

Comment: Thanks - so just to be clear, there isn't any in-built official way? I'd need to write custom code and set `hashListeningEnabled=false` on the base page, right?