# How to open a dialog with jQuery Mobile by calling a URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

may some one tell how to open a dialog in jQuery Mobile just by opening a url like http://example.com/dialog.html

I tried to set the data-role to "dialog", but didn't work.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4c4sC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In your anchor link add data-rel="dialog", your target page can have data-role="page" and still be opened as a dialog

http://jsfiddle.net/4c4sC/5/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not what I asked. I need to open the dialog not by clicking a link, but it should open when you directly open the page.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for -

Is it possible to link to a dialog, and have it display as a dialog?

[jQuery mobile: Meaningful URL for a dialog page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296048/jquery-mobile-meaningful-url-for-a-dialog-page)